# How to send a list of class via ajax to asp.net mvc action?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I use this codes for send list of class via ajax to action.
I get a list by length more than 1 but all of properties value is default.

js:

```
class WorkPlan {
            Id: number;
            Presure: number;
        }

$('#btn-SaveDailyWorkPlan').click(function () {
    try {
        var changedWorkPlan = $('[name*=presure-hour-]');
        var newWorkPlans = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            if ($(changedWorkPlan[i]).attr('data-is-changed') === 'true') {
                var workPlan = new WorkPlan();
                workPlan.Id = parseInt($(changedWorkPlan[i]).data('id'));
                workPlan.Presure = parseFloat($(changedWorkPlan[i]).val());
                newWorkPlans.push(workPlan);
            }
        }
        console.log(newWorkPlans);
        //send for save in db
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Setting/SaveDailyWorkPlan",
            data: { workPlans: newWorkPlans },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex.message);
    }
});
```

action:

```
 public JsonResult SaveDailyWorkPlan(List<WorkPlan> workPlans)
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

I use `JSON.stringify()` method but in this case data dont send to action.

What is problem?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "all of properties value is default"?, Your for loop starts from 0. That my be why you are having length more than 1

Comment: I fill my class by valid data but in action I get default values such as image!

Comment: Some parameter in ajax are missing like type,contentType,dataType.Add the following parameter and try again

Comment: can u try with $.post("/Setting/SaveDailyWorkPlan", { workPlans: newWorkPlans }, "json").done(function(){ ... success code ..}).fail(function(){..error code..}) to check if it do the JSON.stringify ... it's strange not binding